# Django IntegretyError, when try to change ManyToMany field's value

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

### models.py

```
class BaseMedia(AbstractObject):
    staff = models.ManyToManyField('main.Profession', blank=True)
    # etc

class Profession(Id):
    profession = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    creator = models.ForeignKey('main.Creator', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    character = models.ForeignKey('main.Character', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

### forms.py

```
for profession, staff in staff.items():
    for person in staff:
        professions.append(Profession.objects.update_or_create(
            profession=profession,
            creator_id=person.get('creator_id'),
            character_id=person.get('character_id')
        )[0])

instance.staff.set(professions)
```

`instance.staff.set(professions)` from **forms.py** raise:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: update or delete on table "main_profession" violates 
foreign key constraint "main_basemedia_staff_profession_id_075458d2_fk_main_prof" on 
table "main_basemedia_staff"

DETAIL:  Key (id)=(dd032d79-d458-4ead-b05b-da3b419b58a0) is still referenced from table 
"main_basemedia_staff".
```

I absolutely have no idea that's the point of this trouble.

Comment: the form is wrong but I think there are much more errors. For the beginning check out the docs [update_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create)

Comment: @Goran, There is only code from **save** function. And what exactly should I see in this doc?

Comment: you can't update or create bu "creator_id" you must have an obj instance

Comment: unfortunately, it hasn't any effect